# Calculate the uptime percentage/availability of ephemeral pods in kubernetes over a period of time

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, promql

I want to calculate the availability/uptime percentage of ephemeral pods runners that belong to GitHub Action runners.

How should promql query look like to calculate the uptime percentage of ephemeral runners/pods in kubernetes?

Comment: Your question feels opinion based (and thus unsuitable for SO). Can you edit it to request more factual based answers? Also, to answer **how** it can be done, it would be helpful to know what kind of metrics about pods you have.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot to consider in order for you to achieve your goals in monitoring the availability or uptime of ephemeral pod runners for GitHub Action runners. To start off,  you need a tool to do this like Grafana. This will help you monitor and visualize Kubernetes metrics. Also you need to define the criteria that you want to monitor. This is just fo help you start off but there are a lot of things to be done. Here are some helpful links for you. [1][2][3]

[1] https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/installation/kubernetes/

[2] https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/about-self-hosted-runners

[3] https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/resource-metrics-pipeline/

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer but what does the promql query look like? Ephemeral pods kill after job finished so what should be the easiest way to calculate uptime percentage for ephemeral pods/runners